# How to add more button at last of the Custom Post Type Widgets plugins

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i want more link button after showing the post list.here is the screenshot:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3qpe.png

this is the widget given by Custom Post Type Widgets plugin and i have displayed only recent 5 post only so if anyone wanna see more then there must be button so that they can click on that so how can i add more button in Custom Post Type Widgets plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great [article here](https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/06/filter-output-wordpress-widget/) that I borrowed the code from and customised it for your custom posts widget.  Copy and paste the code below into your functions.php file in your child theme directory, you'll need to modify the variable **$widget_output** to include your button, I've made it return a link.

```
function my_filter_dynamic_sidebar_params( $sidebar_params ) {

    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $sidebar_params;
    }

    global $wp_registered_widgets;
    $widget_id = $sidebar_params[0]['widget_id'];

    $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ]['original_callback'] = $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ]['callback'];
    $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ]['callback'] = 'my_custom_widget_callback_function';

    return $sidebar_params;

}
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'my_filter_dynamic_sidebar_params' );

function my_custom_widget_callback_function() {

    global $wp_registered_widgets;
    $original_callback_params = func_get_args();
    $widget_id = $original_callback_params[0]['widget_id'];

    $original_callback = $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ]['original_callback'];
    $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ]['callback'] = $original_callback;

    $widget_id_base = $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ]['callback'][0]->id_base;

    if ( is_callable( $original_callback ) ) {

        ob_start();
        call_user_func_array( $original_callback, $original_callback_params );
        $widget_output = ob_get_clean();

        echo apply_filters( 'widget_output', $widget_output, $widget_id_base, $widget_id );

    }

}

function my_widget_output_filter( $widget_output, $widget_id_base, $widget_id ) {

    if( $widget_id_base === 'custom-post-type-recent-posts') {
        return $widget_output . '<a href="http://examplelink">My Link</a>';
    }

    return $widget_output;

}
add_filter( 'widget_output', 'my_widget_output_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: @AjayPaudel Copy and paste into your functions.php file in your child theme directory.

Comment: Thanks man it works for me but it that link button comes below that widget but by using js i append that link button at the end of that widget

Comment: @AjayPaudel this is unusual because I am appending the button link to the output of the widget so it can only appear after it and not before.  The link is appearing at the bottom of my widget.

Comment: it cames out side the <aside> tag i mean to say it inside that widget section but not inside that particular widget i mean to say

Comment: @AjayPaudel there should be a way of fixing this using PHP, adding additional javascript is not the recommended approach as you're just adding overheads for no reason.